# Две модели в один Formset

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать у себя на Службе небольшую прогамку которая будет вести учет заседаний у начальства. Никак не пойму как работать с формсетами (*formset*). Документацию прочел и на русском и на английском, но как сохранить и прочитать весь “поезд с вагонами” – *formset*, не получается.

Форма документа такова:
Протокол заседания № *nr_document*   от   *date_unfold*

Присутствовали: *employees*

*MeetingItem* – номер пункта, описание (задачи) , срок выполнения, ответственный

*MeetingItem* – номер пункта, описание (задачи) , срок выполнения, ответственный

и тд...

Как связать две модели формы *MeetingHeader* и *MeetingItem* ?
Как в файле view.py использовать *formset_factory* ? 
Как потом прочитать сгенерированный документ ?

Прошу показать или объяснить.

Дальше самостоятельно буду осваивать динамическое добавление/удаление полей как в примере - http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

```
model.py

from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null= True, unique= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.surname)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Meeting(models.Model):
    nr_document = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date_unfold = models.DateField(
           blank=True, null=True)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('Employee')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Proces verbal nr.%s din %s' % (self.nr_document, self.date_unfold)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_unfold']

class MeetingItem(models.Model):
    nr_punct = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_unfold = models.DateField(
           blank=True, null=True)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('Employee')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Employee, Meeting, MeetingItem


class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'

class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = '__all__'

class MeetingItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MeetingItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Employee, Meeting
from .forms import EmployeeForm, MeetingForm, MeetingItemForm

def meeting_item(request):
     MeetingFormSet = formset_factory(MeetingForm)
     MeetingItemFormSet = formset_factory(MeetingItemForm, extra=2)
     if request.method == "POST":
         meeting_formset = MeetingFormSet(request.POST, prefix='meetings')
         meetingItem_formset = MeetingItemFormSet(request.POST, prefix='meetingItems')

     if meeting_formset.is_valid() and meetingItem_formset.is_valid():
         message = "Perfect pass"

         **?????.save()** # здесь не знаю как сохранить

    else:
        message = "NU A MERS PERFECT"
    meeting_formset = MeetingFormSet(prefix='meetings')
    meetingItem_formset = MeetingItemFormSet(prefix='meetingItems')            
    return render_to_response('blog/meeting_item.html', {
         'message': message, 
         'meeting_formset': meeting_formset,
         'meetingItem_formset': meetingItem_formset },
             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
   return render_to_response('blog/meeting_item.html',
             {'meetingItem_formset': MeetingItemFormSet(), 
              'meeting_formset': MeetingFormSet() },
             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
for form in meeting_formset:
    form.save()

for form in meetingItem_formset:
    form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Выдает ошибку валидации

> ValidationError

В строке

```
if meeting_formset.is_valid() and meetingItem_formset.is_valid():
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что в обоих формсетах *manytomany*. Как указать сохранение м2м для формсетов?

Как мне связать шапку протокола с пунктами, чтоб весь этот 'поезд' сохранился все вместе, чтоб потом можно было прочитать, и дать на печать.

К сожалению и с динамическим добавлением и удалением полей, пока тоже глухо, прям как стена.